# pnp sensor on raspberry

Tags: pnp

how do I hook a PNP sensor to a raspberry pi 3?
I know I need an A/D converter, and I've already got a MCP3008.
But apart from that, what else do I need?
The sensor output switches 24v or 0v, I also know I have to bring it down to 3,3V.
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: What sensor? Why do you need an ADC?

Comment: rpi doesn't work with analog signals

Comment: that assumes it is an analogue sensor. You haven't specified what sensor it is, so how do we know.

Answer (score 2):

> The sensor output switches 24 V or 0 V.

That means it's a digital sensor and should be connected to a digital input. You use analog inputs for varying signals which are "analogous" to the physical property you are measuring - e.g., temperature, pressure, etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fISA1C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> I also know I have to bring it down to 3,3V.

So we need to divide the voltage by 3.3 / 24 = 7.3. 68k and 10k as shown in Figure 1 should do the job.

The resistor values are high to keep currents low. If you have a two-wire sensor it may need a certain current in the 'off' condition to power the electronics. In that case we may need to scale the resistors down by a factor of 10 or so. Let us know and post a link to the sensor datasheet.

Comment: http://www.leuze.com/en/deutschland/produkte/schaltende_sensoren/optische_sensoren/lichtschranken_lichttaster_zylindrisch/baureihe_318_kunststoff/lichttaster/rt_hrt_3/selector.php?supplier_aid=50122564&grp_id=1332237561758&lang=eng#{"tab":"2"}

Comment: just click on downloads and find the datasheet in your preferred language...

thanks a lot dude!
btw I'll still need the a/d for the analog sensors

Comment: OK. There's no mention of analog in your question. Industrial analog sensors will be 0 - 10 V or 4 - 20 mA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a voltage divider as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f85NEx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It will work with R1 and R4 as a single 30K resistor, with C1 missing, and with R3 shorted, D1, D2 missing, but the suggested parts add more immunity to

Comment: Invert the diodes before you power on! ;^)

Comment: D1 is mandatory, right?

Comment: "Invert the diodes" fixed- thanks ugh. silly mistake

Comment: D1 is not necessarily mandatory if the 24V is regulated and the wires reasonable length, but it's not a bad idea.